# How to calculate the "stress" done by a php script on the server?

Tags: php, tcpdf

im testing some new libaries on my local webserver, some of them are heavy, like pdf converter ([TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org)). I will like to know how many system resources the php script takes, like the cpu stress. Is there a tecniche to do this using the same php script?

This kind of test is very importand to me because i will like to open a service (im expecting a huge ammount of trafic) were the users will have information directly on pdf format, so my server will have to execute the *html to pdf* script alot in one day. The result of this test will allow me to know what hosting service i need to buy.

I know this seems a question more for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) but i will like a software solution (if it is possible), like i said before, is possible to calculate this on the same php script?

Thanks for any help and orientation! have a nice day!

Comment: Look into `memory_get_usage()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and `getrusage()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrusage.php). `getrusage()` return information can be found here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Load test your webapp with something like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). This will allow you to perform a quick and dirty high level test of your software and infrastructure.

Example:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://yourwebsite/path/to/heavy/script?=params
```

Would make 1000 requests to your heavy script in concurrent batches of 10 and subsequently dump a report with metrics like `requests/second`, `time/request` etc.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-62579.html

```
$stats = exec('uptime');
preg_match('/averages?: ([0-9\.]+),[\s]+([0-9\.]+),[\s]+([0-9\.]+)/', $stats, $regs);
$load = array('1 min' => $regs[1], '5 min' => $regs[2], '15 min' => $regs[3]);
```

[`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) won't be available is safemode is enabled. If it is, try [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [`getrusage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getrusage.php). [`getrusage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getrusage.php) returns [the struct from the linux call](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) `getrusage`.

In case you were wondering, the `$load` array will contain the average CPU load for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.